# Shared Method with callback argument

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

I would like to create a pattern like the following:

```
namespace SharedUtilities
{
    public partial class PartialClass
    {
        public void DoSomethingInteresting()
        {
            DoSomethingPlatformSpecific();
        }

        partial void DoSomethingPlatformSpecific();
}
```

}

But I would like to add a callback argument so that I can pass in a different callback depending on the platform. Can anyone point me in the right direction here? I have been reading up on Action, EventHandler<>, and delegate, but I'm not sure which one to use in this scenario. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Consider [abstract factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) instead...

Comment: I did consider the abstract factory pattern, but I wanted to fully explore the alternatives in an effort to make a more educated decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do that and handle this kind of scenario, the simplest one would be like this -

```
namespace SharedUtilities
{
    public partial class PartialClass
    {
        public void DoSomethingInteresting(Action<Type1, Type2> action)
        {
            //code logic
            action(p1, p2);
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it like this -

- With lambda

  ```
  (new SharedUtilities.PartialClass()).DoSomethingInteresting((param1, param2)=>
  {
       //codes
  });
  ```
- Without Lambda

  ```
  public void DoSomethingInterestingSpecific(Type1 param1, Type2 param2)
  {
      //code logic

  }

  (new SharedUtilities.PartialClass()).DoSomethingInteresting(DoSomethingInterestingSpecific);
  ```

That is one way of doing this, there are other ways too, like abstract factory pattern, event delegate callback, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Func<...> has a return value, Action<...> does not.  Callbacks should usually be Action<...>

If you want to structure the code such that classes other than the one calling the function can be notified when it's complete, define an event.